# Netware 3.12 some or all volume segments can not be loaded

Tags: networking, dos

i have an old pc that has a network drive by netware 3.12 in dos 6.22 . i backup hard disk by microsoft disk2vhd and now have an vhd file. i add vhd file in virtualbox and dos successfully boot. i can input `server` command, but when i input `server` command show  this error:

`volume sys could not be loaded
some or all volume segments cannot be located`

and virtualbox screen image:

[image: my error]

why this error show? netware was successfully work in my old pc but in virtualbox does not work,why?

Comment: Your screen shot is unreadable.  Consider uploading a higher resolution/sized one.

Comment: i upload a higher size and resolution image of error,thanks for ur comment

Answer (score 1):

DOS works because it uses the VM BIOS to access HDDs. Netware for performance reason does not use the BIOS to access HDDs. What is likely happening is Netware does not have the required device driver to access the disk controller exposed by the VM. As a result Netware cannot find the SYS volume. I have never tried to install Netware in a VM so I am unsure where you'd go to find appropriate drivers.

I found the following that might be worth your while to explore to see if it can help: https://www.foxdogstudios.com/installing-netware-3-12-on-virtual-box

Comment: can i recover files in netware file server? can i copy files from my old pc via netware network by windows? what is partition format of netware?

Comment: if i backup my old pc by Microsoft Disk2vhd then Netware partiton on dos partition backuped or not? i guess this partition not backuped by disk2vhd, how can i backup this partition?

Comment: The file on the Netware file server volume are not readable from DOS or Windows -- they use a format that is proprietary to Netware. There might be some 3rd party software to let you access those but I haven't never done that.